# MCC API Players Names into Text Files

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, rewriting

I'm currently playing with the [MCC API](https://api.mcchampionship.com/docs/#/) and I want to put every players name in their own text file within their team folder. This is the code that I have currently:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get("https://api.mcchampionship.com/v1/participants")

# TEAMS

# RED
# Player 1
DATA_Red_p1 = open("./Players/Red/player1.txt", "w")
DATA_Red_p1.write(str(r.json()['data']['RED'][0]['username']))
DATA_Red_p1.close()
# Player 2
DATA_Red_p2 = open("./Players/Red/player2.txt", "w")
DATA_Red_p2.write(str(r.json()['data']['RED'][1]['username']))
DATA_Red_p2.close()
# Player 3
# ...
# Player 4
# ...
```

I have the same code copy and pasted (excluding the import and the api fetch) for each team, just with different variables and file paths. The teams are: Red, orange, yellow, lime, green, cyan, aqua, blue, purple and pink. I was just wondering if there was an easier way of writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that using a for-loop. However this will output 10 text files, is that desired? Or do you prefer to store all in 1 text file?

```
import requests
#import os

r = requests.get("https://api.mcchampionship.com/v1/participants")
response = r.json()
file_path = './Players/Red'
#file_path = os.getcwd()
for i, color in enumerate(response['data'].keys()):
    if color != 'SPECTATORS' and color != 'NONE':
        f = open(file_path + '/player' + str(i+1) + '.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(response['data'][color][0]['username']))
        f.close()
```

Output:

```
player1.txt
player2.txt
player3.txt
player4.txt
player5.txt
player6.txt
player7.txt
player8.txt
player9.txt
player10.txt
```

If you would like to save the list into 1 file, you could do this:

```
f = open(file_path + '/players.txt', 'a')
for color in response['data'].keys():
    if color != 'SPECTATORS' and color != 'NONE':
        f.write(str(response['data'][color][0]['username']) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: After trying to run the first bit of code you sent, I ran into an error stating "NameError: name 'i' is not defined".

Comment: Oops! I got confused and edited the wrong part of the code.. I've reverted to the previous (enumerate) version!